# Swift: Recognizing Scrolling Through UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a `UIViewController` that creates custom `UIView` objects and inserts them into a `UIScrollView`. The `UIViewController` attaches a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to each `UIView`. Is there anything I can do to allow scrolling of the `UIScrollView` even when it is being touched through the custom `UIView` objects while still allowing their `UIPanGestureRecognizers` (which are configured to change x coordinates only) to work?

Here's a screenshot of what I mean. The blue rectangles are the custom `UIView` objects, and the white background is the `UIScrollView`.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After doing some more research, it seems like using `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`  (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html) is the way to do this. The problem is that since I'm new to Swift, I don't know how to make use of it. If anyone knows how to use 
`gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:)`, I would greatly appreciate guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

It's all about using `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`.

At the top, you do `class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Then, in the class body, you add this method:

`func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }`

And finally, to the `UIView` on top, you add `panRecognizer.delegate = self` (`panRecognizer` is the variable referencing the `UIView`'s `UIGestureRecognizer`

Comment: Can you add a little more code detail please. I did not get the UIView part. I am also new to swift

Comment: This is all of the code needed to solve this specific problem. Which part is it that you need help with?